# Gmail , gets email message without history

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am using Gmail mailbox and get the message using imap_fetchbody. By default, if the message is a reply to a previous message, it contains the previous message. How can I get the message without the previous message?

Note that we use 2 languages, so it might be a problem to cut the message where there is a ">". For example, suppose this is my message:

```
תגובה בעברית
 
 ‫בתאריך יום א׳, 23 במאי 2021 ב-17:28 מאת ... <‪shanishalel89@gmail.com
 ‬‏>:‬
 
 > reply on it
 >
 > ‫בתאריך יום א׳, 23 במאי 2021 ב-17:05 מאת <‪emoodlesmessage@gmail.com‬‏>:‬
 >
 >> only English
 >
 >
```

and I get it as string, I can cut where I have '>'. but the second line will remain.

Comment: Do you mean your email contains both English and probably Hebrew, thus simply skipping lines that begin with > doesn't work? Can you give an example of such a message?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an email or gmail related issue specifically. It seems more like a text processing issue because the `>` that are in the email are just part of the message and there's no mechanism to remove them via imap so maybe share the code you're trying to solve this problem with so we can give you some coding help